# Inline style element appers in develoer window but not when viewing source code

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-devtools, developer-tools

I am looking at a form that has a [captcha](http://www.captcha.net/). The CSS being applied has made it all whacky looking. I'm about to diagnose the issue, and I'm looking at the styles being applied in my Google chrome developer window. For each individual rule, there is light grey text in the top right of the box that says where the code came from. The one rule I'm interested in indicates it came from `<style></style>`, which I assume is an inline style rule. Clicking on the source, it takes me to the `<style>` element that is defined and sure enough the rules are there. These rules don't exist in the source file, so I'm pretty sure the element is appended through javascript. When I hit `ctrl + u` to view the source code, the `<style>` element is not there.

How can I see an element that exists in the developer window without it existing in the view source code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elements created by JavaScript are not visible in source code, that is because they are created dynamicaly, and when you use "view page source" then you get source code of page returned by server without executing JavaScript.

Comment: Not only Javascript but any other dynamic script that modifies the raw HTML. Of course the most obvious is JavaScript, but it also can be more complex system, like PHP or ASP for example (and so on). Just to make this a little bit more clear :)

Comment: PHP is server side, it can't be executed on client side, I think same is for ASP :)

Comment: Yes, but anyway it may have a function to insert something that doesn't appear in the pure HTML. I cited PHP and ASP, but there can be other ones...

Comment: Ok, sorry. Maybe I was a little bit confused here. I agree, PHP and ASP really can't do anything on client side, however the important point here is  that any dynamic script in the page can modify the Page Source. Sorry for the inconvenience :)